# iPhone app crashing with Distribution Codesign

Tags: iphone, distribution, codesign

The app that I am building is crashing when I put it on my device with a distribution certificate. It runs fine in the debug configuration with a provisioning profile. When I install it from XCode with the Distribution certificate, it gives me the error

```
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 291.
```

The console in the iPhone Configuration Utility gives me the error

```
<Warning>: Application 'App' exited abnormally with signal 10: Bus error
```

Can anyone help me out here?

I'm still working on building my knowledge of iPhone programming, so sorry for easy/redundant questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Applications signed with Distribution Certificate cannot be installed on device. They are meant to be submitted into AppStore through iTunes Connect.